# No overload for method AddComponent' takes 0 arguments

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm new here. can you help me with this?

Since Unity 5 this method is deprecated

```
UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent(gameObject, "Assets/Parley Assets/Scripts/Dialog.cs (150,5)", dialogClass);
```

and the auto updater replaced it with a call to

```
UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent<Dialog>();
```

But i get error, anyway

Comment: Please add at least one tag for the programming language or framework and explain what you are unable to do.

Comment: Done, hope it's ok now

Comment: It definitely makes more chance to catch the attention of someone who can help you

Answer (score 1):

Ok fixed just now,

for those who have the same problem just replace this

```
UnityEngineInternal.APIUpdaterRuntimeServices.AddComponent(gameObject, "Assets/Parley Assets/Scripts/Dialog.cs (150,5)", dialogClass);
```

with this

```
gameObject.AddComponent<Dialog>();
```

Comment: In our case which was a js file we got it fixed like this by looking at your answer. gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(ImportManager));

Answer (score 0):

I had to supply the type of the dialogClass variable when calling AddComponent to make it fully work:

gameObject.AddComponent(Type.GetType(dialogClass));

Hope this helps you.